# Submit button not working when there are multiple fields present

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

When there is multiple address generated, the Submit button does not work.

I've tried to solve it with JavaScript.

```php
@foreach ($userDetails as $addr)
    <div class="order_container">
        <input type="hidden" name="userName" value="{{$addr['customer_name']}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="userMobile" value="{{$addr['customer_mobile']}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="userSelectAddress" value="{{$addr['customer_address']}}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="userSelectAddressId" value="{{$addr['customer_address_id']}}" id="id1"/>


        {{$addr['customer_address']}} <br>
        {{$addr['customer_name']}} <br>
        {{$addr['customer_mobile']}} <br>
        {{$addr['location_name']}}<br>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

JS

```js
function validate_radio() {
    /*alert("fail");
    return false;*/
    // let inpObj = document.getElementById("id1").value.checked;
    if (document.getElementById('id1').checked) {
        alert("pass");
    } else {
        alert("else");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I expect the submit button to work no matter how many address i have selected.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the submit button? Kindly share full code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a constant id.

`id="id1"`

Make sure that your ids are all unique. You cannot have two elements with the same id on the page.

Comment: The part where this is a for loop. He's definitely creating multiple elements, all with a generated id of "id1".

Comment: Although you're correct, this doesn't solve OP problem. What will he do with `document.getElementById('id1')`, I suppose it should be changed also.

Comment: Yes, there are other code issues stemming from this problem. Solving this is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

An ID has to be unique in a page. 
So you have to generate a different ID for each user.

You can do that with a variable that begin at 0 and that you increment with 1 in every loop : `$i++`

Answer (score 0):

The issue has already been identified as a duplicated ID attribute - one solution would be to remove the ID entirely and use sibling and parent type selectors to navigate the DOM tree - in conjunction with `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` the use of ID attributes is of limited value in many cases.

Initially select all the `checkbox` elements of this particular name `userSelectAddressId` using `querySelectorAll` and assign an event listener to each. Once the listener is assigned it is easy to access the element itself to determine if it is checked or not - then you can use parent &/or sibling selectors to find the values of elements nearby if desired. I believe jQuery has native methods for this too.

```
@foreach ($userDetails as $addr)
       <div class="order_container">
           <input type="hidden" name = "userName" value="{{$addr['customer_name']}}" >
           <input type="hidden" name = "userMobile" value="{{$addr['customer_mobile']}}" >
           <input type="hidden" name = "userSelectAddress" value="{{$addr['customer_address']}}" >
           <input type="checkbox" name="userSelectAddressId" value="{{$addr['customer_address_id']}}" />


           {{$addr['customer_address']}} <br>
           {{$addr['customer_name']}} <br>
           {{$addr['customer_mobile']}} <br>
           {{$addr['location_name']}}<br>
       </div>
@endforeach
```

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="checkbox"][name="userSelectAddressId"]' ) ).forEach( input=>{
    input.addEventListener('click', e=>{
        if( e.target.checked ){
            /* use this to call `validate_radio()`?  */
            let fields=e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="hidden"]' );
            let data=Array.prototype.slice.call( fields ).map( field=>{
                return [ field.name, field.value ].join('=')
            }).join('&')

            alert('pass: +data);
        }
    })
});
```